# How to remove an object from an array, where the object conforms to a protocol?

Tags: arrays, swift

I am keeping track of a number of delegate objects in an array `delegates`

To qualify as a valid delegate the objects need to conform to the `BSBSystemDelegate` protocol.

So here is the array declaration:

```swift
private var delegates: [BSBSystemDelegate] = []
```

When an object registers with the BSBSystem, it is appended to the array:

```swift
public func registerDelegateWith(_ viewController: BSBSystemDelegate)
{
    self.delegates.append(viewController)
}
```

That's working fine.

The problem I'm running into with swift and it's awful and confusing syntax is when I need to 'deregister' a delegate i.e. remove it from the array, if it exists.

Here's what I've tried:

```swift
public function deregisterDelegate(_ viewController: BSBSystemDelegate)
{
    for delegate in self.delegates
    {
        if delegate === viewController
        {
            self.delegates.removeAll(where: viewController)
        }
    }
}
```

That doesn't work.

I just want to remove the object in the array when it's the same object I'm asking to remove.

I've been fighting swift for over an hour. Can someone please explain where I'm going wrong?

Here's is Apple's example:

[image]

And here is my code and the crazy dumb error it keeps giving me:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self.delegates.removeAll(where: { $0 === viewController })` will work but your protocol needs to be declared as class-bound in order to use the `===` operator which only works with reference types.

You would have to declare your protocol as:

```
protocol BSBSystemDelegate: AnyObject {
    ...
}
```

The error message isn't useful because the compiler is confused but if you break out your closure declaration on to a separate line:

```
let shouldBeRemoved: (BSBSystemDelegate) -> Bool = { $0 === viewController }
self.delegates.removeAll(where: shouldBeRemoved)
```

You get a more useful `binary operator '===' cannot be applied to two 'BSBSystemDelegate' operands` message.

Comment: Hi Dan. Thank you. That worked, but I don't understand why. Could you please try to explain it to me like I'm slow? ;)

Comment: He did explain. The `===` operator can only be applied to reference types (class objects). That's because value types like structs are always copied, and never referred to by reference, thus two structs will never be the same object. By declaring your protocol as `AnyObject` (or `class`) it tells the compiler that objects that conform to that protocol will be reference objects, and thus that it's legal to compare them using the `===` operator.

Comment: Thank you Duncan, that completely explains it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you change your protocol to make it class-bound, as described by Dan, you could also use code like this:

```
if let index = array.firstIndex(where: { $0 === aFoo }) {
    array.remove(at: index)
}
```

That would probably be faster for a large array, since it would stop on the first occurence of a match. (`removeAll(where:)` will always check every element in the array for a match.)

However, the code above would only remove the first instance of the object from the array if the exact same object has been added more than once.

Comment: Thank you. I need to understand what 'Class-Bound' means and why putting ': AnyObject' worked because I have no idea that I should have done that. Swift is NOT a friendly or clear syntactically or grammatically easy language. Obj-C was much better.

Comment: A class-bound protocol means that only reference types (and not value types) can conform to it. Obj-C doesn't really have value types so all Obj-C protocols are class-bound.

Comment: Thanks Dan. I appreciate the response.